# The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an app hosted on heroku and I get the following error when I try to go to example.com/pages/movies

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

However it works when I go to it under localhost:3000/pages/movies

I am not sure if it is a routing error or what, I am pretty clueless right now.

here is my routes.rb

```
InstallRails::Application.routes.draw do

  get "pages/movies"
  resources :sessions, only: :destroy
  resources :install_steps, path: 'steps'
  root 'welcome#index'

  get 'test', to: 'welcome#test'

end
```

Comment: Can you post heroku logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routing files misses which controller action should handle requests to that url. Something like:

```
get '/pages/movies', to: 'pages#movies'
```

What means that the `movies` action from the `pages_controller` will handle the request.